# Codeigniter pass the actual number of rows (not limited) from model to controller

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Just want to display paginated search results and the number of results (for example "Found 17 results") using Codeigniter. Everything works ok but it displays "Found 5 results" instead "Found 17 results". Please check my code below and help me to pass the actual number of rows (not limited) from model to controller.

My Model:

```
public function did_get($city, $limit, $offset) { 

    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('table');

    $this->db->where('city', $city); 

    $query = $this->db->get();

    $this->db->limit($limit, $offset);   

    if ($query && $query->num_rows() > 0) {

        return $query->result_array();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

My Controller:

```
            if ($this->model_get->did_get($city, $limit, $offset)) {

            $data["count"] = $this->model_get->did_get_count($city);

            $data["results"] = $this->model_get->did_get($city, $limit, $offset);

            $this->load->view("view_results",$data);
```

Comment: i think im not understanding the question...

Comment: Perhaps I could not explain the problem. For example I got 17 rows from database and displayed them using pagination (5 rows on each page). I also would like to display that "17 rows have been found". So I need to pass number of rows 17 from my model to my view. As I use LIMIT option, it returns number of rows 5 instead of 17.

Comment: you want to increase the limit or remove the limit entirely?

Comment: Ah! ok. Maybe you could return an array. In $arr["rows"] you save the number of rows and in $arr["result"] you save the limited rowset

Comment: yes but do not know how to return two arrays from one model.

Comment: @CIRCLE I just want to return the number of rows from my model to my controller

Comment: You are getting 5 rows, because you are setting the limit the 5 rows. If you want to get the total amount of rows, you can `count` the query without the limit clause, then rerun the query with the limit for the actual data from the rows.

Comment: @Wold, I cannot remove limit because I use pagination

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just remove the limit clause and get the actual counts

```
public function did_get($city, $limit=0, $offset=0) 
{ 

    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('table');

    $this->db->where('city', $city); 

    $query = $this->db->get();

    //set limit only if $limit and $offset are provided
    if($limit && $offset) $this->db->limit($limit, $offset);   

    if ($query && $query->num_rows() > 0) 
    {
        return $query->result_array();
    } 
    else 
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

and your controller

```
$data["results"] = $this->model_get->did_get($city);
$data['count'] = count($data["results"]);              
$this->load->view("view_results",$data);
```

Comment: I need limit and offset because I use codeigniter pagination

Comment: @EducateYourself In that case, I would say just write a function that returns the total count that you can use for display purpose.

Comment: Do you mean 2 functions in the model? one for returning the results and one for returning the number of rows?

Comment: @EducateYourself - yes, it is not highly efficient however it will do what you need without disturbing any of the existing code. Just make `$data['count'] = $this->model_get->did_get_count($city);`, where `did_get_count()` will be the same function, but returning count instead or records, and it will not have limit or offset it in.

Comment: I thought it is possible to do with one function. Whatever, I will try to use two functions .

Comment: I tried with two functions as well but $count still is 5. It's very strange. I do not understand what can be the problem.

Comment: @EducateYourself - can you update the new code you have written in your question so I can take a look?

Comment: I have just added my controller code to my question. Could you check please.

Comment: @EducateYourself - what is the result you are getting in `$data["count"] = $this->model_get->did_get_count($city);`?

Comment: Now I get all the 17 rows displayed on my view without pagination, no page numbers are shown and I get "5 results were found" on the top of the displayed results.

Answer (score 1):

I cant test this but check something like this:

```
public function did_get($city, $limit, $offset) { 

    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('table');

    $this->db->where('city', $city); 

    $query = $this->db->get();

    $array["count"] = $query->num_rows();

    $this->db->limit($limit, $offset);   

    if ($query && $query->num_rows() > 0) {

        $array["results"] = $query->result_array();
    } else {
        $array["results"] = false;
    }
    return $array;
}
```

then, in your controller you can access data easy:

```
$limit = 5;

$this->load->view("view_results",$this->model_get->did_get($city, $limit, $offset));
```

Comment: it still displays 'Found 5 results'

Answer (score 1):

Since you need to keep the limit clause for pagination, why don't you return an array with the two values?

**Your Model**

```
public function did_get($city, $limit=0, $offset=0) 
{ 

    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('table');

    $this->db->where('city', $city); 

    $query = $this->db->get();

    $count = count($query->result_array());

    //set limit only if $limit and $offset are provided
    if($limit && $offset) $this->db->limit($limit, $offset);   

    if ($query && $query->num_rows() > 0) 
    {
        $rows = $query->result_array();
        $results = array (
            "count" => $count,
            "rows" => $rows
        );
        return $results;
    } 
    else 
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Your Controller**

```
$limit = 5;

$results = $this->model_get->did_get($city, $limit, $offset);

$data['count'] = $results["count"];

$data['results'] = $results["rows"];              

$this->load->view("view_results",$data);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need but I cannot understand why it is still displaying "5 results were found". Could you check what is wrong with $count

Comment: I don't know what to tell you. Is it possible that there are only 5 rows in the table? Are you using all the code I provided, both for the controller and the model? It should be working properly.

Comment: yes, there are more than 5 rows in the table. I even tried to use two functions in my model but the result was the same. Please check my updated question.

Comment: If you are using `did_get_count()` for the number of rows and still getting the wrong number, then it might be your database. Could you possibly include that in your question?